# Search Bar with prepareForSegue for DetailViewController

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisearchbar, segue, uisearchresultscontroller

I'm implementing the search bar for my project. The search part is ok. I can display the raw data and filter the data with the search text. When I tap on the cell of the search result tableView, it didn't transition to the detail view. But for the raw data I can transition to the detail view. I use the `prepareForSegue` method as I'm using storyboard.
Here's the code so far,

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"Book Detail Segue"]) {

    BookDetailsTVC *bookDetailsTVC = segue.destinationViewController; // for the detail view controller
    bookDetailsTVC.delegate = self;

    if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) { // The if block is not working
        NSLog(@"Search Display Controller");
        bookDetailsTVC.book = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex: self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Default Display Controller");
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        bookDetailsTVC.book = [self.objects objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    }
}
}
```

When I tried using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, I can transition to the detail view. But I got error message like that:

- `Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.`
- `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <BookDetailsTVC: 0x69b5300>.`

Here's the code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    BookDetailsTVC *bookDetailsTVC = [[BookDetailsTVC alloc] init];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

    bookDetailsTVC.book = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex: self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Book Detail Segue" sender:self];

    NSLog(@"Search Display Controller");
} else {

    bookDetailsTVC.book = [self.objects objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Book Detail Segue" sender: self];

    NSLog(@"Default Display Controller");
}
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 20):

The problem is solved,
Change this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];`

to

`UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];`

and in the prepareForSegue method, you can use the self.searchDisplayController.active to check the current tableview

```
if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
    NSLog(@"Search Display Controller");
    bookDetailsTVC.book = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex: self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Default Display Controller");
    bookDetailsTVC.book = [self.objects objectAtIndex: self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
}
```

Comment: That fixed it for me too!  I've been trying to solve this elusive problem for my first app for a week or so now!  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: `self.searchDisplayController.active` part has saved my night!! Thank you very much. I was following this tutorial and couldn't make it work: http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view your solution solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks! In my case the issue was using self.tableView instead of self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        self.selectedPerson = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        PersonasDetalle *pd = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PersonaDetalle"];
        pd.persona = self.selectedPerson;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:pd animated:YES];

    }
}
```